# How to convert int64 datatype columns of parquet file to timestamp in SparkSQL data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here my DataFrame looks like this:

```
+----------------+-------------+
|   Business_Date|         Code|
+----------------+-------------+
|1539129600000000|          BSD|
|1539129600000000|          BTN|
|1539129600000000|          BVI|
|1539129600000000|          BWP|
|1539129600000000|          BYB|
+----------------+-------------+
```

I wanted to convert the `Business_Date` column from `bigint` to `timestamp` value while loading data into hive table.

How can I do this?

Comment: How to read bigint timestamp field from parquet file? I am getting error 'Unable to create Parquet converter for data type "timestamp" whose Parquet type is optional int64 timestamp' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=ntile#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) which will

> Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system time zone in the given format.

It appears that your `Business_Date` needs to be divided by 1M to convert to seconds.

For example:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, col

df = df.withColumn(
    "Business_Date",
    from_unixtime(col("Business_Date")/1000000).cast("timestamp")
)
df.show()
#+---------------------+----+
#|Business_Date        |Code|
#+---------------------+----+
#|2018-10-09 20:00:00.0|BSD |
#|2018-10-09 20:00:00.0|BTN |
#|2018-10-09 20:00:00.0|BVI |
#|2018-10-09 20:00:00.0|BWP |
#|2018-10-09 20:00:00.0|BYB |
#+---------------------+----+
```

`from_unixtime` returns a string so you can cast the result to a `timestamp`.

Now the new schema:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- Business_Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer,  I am able see data type as long instead of timestamp, how we can convert that to timestamp type, also can we keep only one column with right value and other can excluded?

Comment: @ASK you can overwrite the column if you specify the same name in `withColumn` and assign the result back to the original DataFrame.