# How to select 13 digit timestamp column from parquet file,convert it to date and store as a data frame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Since I am newbie to Apache spark and Scala methods, I want to perform the following needs.

**-Read specific column from parquet file(13 Digit timestamp).**

**-Convert the timestamp to ordinary date format(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).**

**-Store the result as another column in dataset.**

I can read the timestamp using the following code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST_APP").setMaster("local")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlcon=new SQLContext(sc)
    val Testdata = sqlcon.read.parquet("D:\\TestData.parquet")
    val data_eve_type_end=Testdata.select(Testdata.col("heading.timestamp")).where(Testdata.col("status").equalTo("Success")).toDF("13digitTime")
  }
}
```

and I tried to convert the timestamp using the reference link below

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/54354790/9493078]

But it doesn't working for me.I don't know actually whether I am fetched the data into a dataframe correctly or not.Anyway that makes an output as a table with columnname **13digitTime** and values as some numbers with size 13 digit.

When I am trying to do code from link mentioned above it shows the error as

```
WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`13digitTime` / 1000000)' due to data type mismatch:
```

I am expecting for data frame with 2 columns in which one should contain the 13 digit timestamp and other should contain converted time from 13 digit to general date format(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).

I wish to kindly get a solution,Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some example of heading.timestamp?

Comment: @ApurbaPandey 

for example: 1551552902793

Comment: sqlcon.read.parquet will return a dataframe itself. All you need to do is add a new column using withcolumn method. This should work. val data_eve_type_end = Testdata.withColumn("13digitTime", from_unixtime($"heading.timestamp"))

Comment: `val date_conv=data_eve_type_end.select(col("timestamp_value").as("UNIX TIME"),from_unixtime(col("timestamp_value")/1000).cast("timestamp").as("GENERAL TIME"))`


@ApurbaPandey This is my code look like now.

Comment: @ApurbaPandey It Works fine.Thanks for the valuable Help.How to Mark this as Correct answer?

Comment: You can an answer correct not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlcon.read.parquet will return a dataframe itself. All you need to do is add a new column using withcolumn method. This should work.

```
val data_eve_type_end = Testdata.withColumn("13digitTime", from_unixtime($"heading.timestamp"))
```

I updated my code like this in which the 13 digit unix time converted into 10 digit by dividing by 1000 and cast it to tiimestamp.

```
val date_conv=data_eve_type_end.select(col("timestamp_value").as("UNIX TIME"),from_unixtime(col("timestamp_value")/1000).cast("timestamp").as("GENERAL TIME"))
```

and output is like

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|    UNIX TIME|       GENERAL TIME|
+-------------+-------------------+
|1551552902793|  2019-03-0 6:55:02|
```